# Is there a way to create an EventBridge rule based on a specific field in the output of a StepFunction?

Tags: json, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I need to create an EventBridge rule based on a specific field in the output of a StepFunction. The only issue is the output should be a JSON, but the event bridge rule stringify's it. I don't see a way to convert it back to JSON in the event pattern.

Here is what the event bridge rule receives from the step function

```
{
    "detail-type": "Step Functions Execution Status Change",
    "source": "aws.states",
    "detail": {
        "status": "SUCCEEDED",
        "input": "{\n  \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}",
        "output": "{\"fraudStatus\":\"RELEASE\",\"screening_status\":{\"status\":\"RELEASE\"}}",
        "inputDetails": {
            "included": true
        },
        "outputDetails": {
            "included": true
        },
        "error": null,
        "cause": null
    }
}
```

And here is the event pattern:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.states"],
  "detail-type": ["Step Functions Execution Status Change"],
  "detail": {
    "status": ["SUCCEEDED"],
    "output": {
      "fraudStatus": ["RELEASE"]
    }
  }
}
```

I need the eventbridge rule to trigger when the `fraudStatus` in the output is `"RELEASE"`, but since it is a string I'm unable to do that. And from what I can tell it doesn't look like you can check for a substring either

I don't see any functions that parse to JSON, and I don't see any [functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html) to check for a substring